# OpenGL/TK Modify change single pixel of image

Tags: c#, opengl, textures, opentk

I want to change a single pixel of the bound texture.

I know i could have a 1x1 bitmap, and get the bitmap data of that, and then pass that in:

```
GL.TexSubImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, pixel.X, pixels.Y, 1, 1, OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Bgra, PixelType.UnsignedByte, bmpData.scan0);
```

However that seems ridiculously complicated for such a simple task of modifying one pixel. Is there a simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a simpler way of doing this?

No. At least, not as far as OpenGL is concerned.

In general, people don't want to change *one* texel. If they're doing uploads, its because they want to update an entire region of texture data. And CPU->GPU DMA operations are designed around that fact.

As for the OpenTK part (creating bitmaps, locking, etc), you don't have to create a bitmap. You can use one of the [TexSubImage2D overloads](http://www.opentk.com/files/doc/class_open_t_k_1_1_graphics_1_1_open_g_l_1_1_g_l.html#ad5f917127cfe97f6f3176939623cd66b) to pass a C# array.

Comment: Ok, cool thanks. I had totally overlooked the fact that i could pass arrays, that should make things easier.

Comment: Oh wait, having an issue my attempt to make a pixel red failed. The pixel became transparent.


GL.TexSubImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, X, Y, 1, 1, OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Rgba, PixelType.UnsignedInt, new uint[]{0xFFFF0000});

Comment: @Randomman159: That sounds like an interesting question. Maybe you should ask it by clicking the "Ask Question" button. Comments are for commenting, not asking questions.